# Spectrogram in matlab - time axis format

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, spectrogram

I have a tone burst signal from 0.20 ms to 0.40 ms. From 0 to 0.20ms and from 0.40ms to 3.27ms it is zero. I did fft which shows frequency content around 25 kHz. The number of fft points is 32768 which is also the length of the time-domain signal.

I am trying to plot spectrogram in Matlab with the following code snippet

```
nfft = 32768;
dT = 1e-6;
fs = 1/dT;
window = hamming(nfft)
spectrogram(signal,window,[],nfft,fs)
```

Using this I am getting accurate frequency description but the time axis is a problem.

Zoomed in time domain signal:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM2xw.png]

Spectogram at 25  kHz:

[image]

Comment: Whats `signal` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **cannot** get a representation that is accurate **both** in the time and frequency domains. This is the [uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle)  of the Fourier transform.

What you **can** do is **trade off** time and frequency resolution by changing the **window length**. Compare the two spectrograms below, obtained with different window lengths. The signal (figure 1) is similar to that in your question.

- The first spectrogram (figure 2) uses a long window, which gives good frequency resolution but poor time resolution. Note how the signal frequency of 10 Hz is resolved, but time information is very coarse.
- Conversely, the second spectrogram (figure 3) uses a short window, which provides good time resolution but poor frequency resolution. As is seen, the signal frequency cannot be resolved, but its time location and shape are more accurate.

```
% Define signal
fs = 500; % sampling frequency
t = 0:1/fs:6; % time axis
fm = 10; % signal (carrier) frequency
s = cos(2*pi*fm*t).* exp(-5*(t-2).^2);
figure
plot(t,s)

% Spectrogram with long window
figure
nfft = 500;
window = hamming(nfft);
spectrogram(s,window,[],nfft,fs), view([90 -90])

% Spectrogram with short window
figure
nfft = 50;
window = hamming(nfft);
spectrogram(s,window,[],nfft,fs), view([90 -90])
```

[image]

[image]

[image]